# *this* object is "undefined" inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a utility function for my React project and it will be used within a React component to manage some behaviors.

During the development process I discovered that the object *this* within my function (not a React component) returned *undefined*. I would use the keyword *this* because I would chain the functions (fn1().fn2().fn3()) to create a kind of declarative experience for those who want to use my function.

How to reproduce the behavior?

1. Create a new React project with the package "create-react-app"
2. Create a new JS file (choose the name you want)
3. Inside the new JS file write a new function like this:

   ```
   function foo() {
     console.log(this)
   }
   ```
4. Call the function wherever you want: inside or outside a React component. Eg. (index.js)

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { foo } from "../../../validation/test";
   import "./App.css";

   class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {};
     }

     render() {
       foo();

       return <h1>Hello Stack Overflow Community....</h1>;
     }
   }

   export default App;
   ```
5. Take a look to the browser console.

I tried in a node environment, but I'm not facing this problem.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Please edit this Q and add code example (Too General Q).https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But which type of code example does the community need? I explained how to reproduce the behavior.... But ok, I will edit my question...

Comment: `foo` is not part of the class so its in the global scope.

Comment: Meta commentary about downvotes or your guesses about others' motivations do no belong in the question. I've edited them out. If you have a question about your question or Stack Overflow in general, ask a question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ok @HereticMonkey. Thanks

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks Daniel. But _undefined_ returns also inside a functional component. Is it the same reason? It is related to the scope?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try foo.bind(this)() instead of foo()? This way it gives the context to your function and this would refer to the class from which it was called from.

Answer (score 0):

Now, after further research and reading, I think I am able to answer my own question.

Why "*this*" was *undefined* in the case mentioned in my question?

The keyword *this* is always a reference to an object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). However, in my case I did not perform any operation necessary to assign the keyword *this* a reference to the function object, I only executed the function ( *foo()* ).

The image below shows the value of *this* keyword:

[image]

Following that, instead:

1. I created an instance of the *foo()* object (see the red arrow in the below image)
2. I executed the *foo2()* function (instance of the foo() object) within a React component and as expected, the keyword *this* is now referenced to the function object and I will be able to make method chaining .

[image]

Any integration or correction of my answer will be appreciated.

Thanks to all contributors.